# Issue in Cloudant to Dash DB sync on bluemix: Documents lost in transit

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, dashdb, cloudant-sdp

Few documents have just vanished in sync between Cloudant to Dash DB. On Cloudant side, the count of messages in main & overflow table is different than the actual count in dash db tables. Any clue how to find those documents?

[image: Count shown on cloudant side for sync job]

[image: Count different in dashdb for synced table]

[image: Count different in dashdb for overflow table]

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to recover the lost documents would be by using the RESCAN function. That will re-load all documents currently in Cloudant to dashDB. Just beware that it will drop existing tables and records before it performs the reload.

If you want the Cloudant support team to investigate the specific cause for this loss, please open a ticket with support@cloudant.com and make sure to mention your account details!